# How to difirentiate between integer and decimal fields when using OracleDataReader.GetFieldType(i)

Tags: c#

I am using `OracleDataReader.GetFieldType(i)` to get the returned recordset fields of a stored procedure in order to generate a CS class file that could be used to call this SP (I need to define a property for the class for each field returned by the SP - so I need the data type of the field).

The problem is I cannot determine if the field type should be an integer or decimal, because `GetFieldType(i)` returns `System.Decimal` if the field was of type `Number`, so I could not determine if the field was an integer or a double/decimal value.

Here is the code I am using to get the fields returned by the SP:

```
#region OpenDBConnection
oConnection.ConnectionString = sDBConnectionString;
OracleCommand oCommand;
oConnection.Open();
#endregion

#region GetTheFieldsOfTheGetProcedure
oCommand = new OracleCommand("SPName", oConnection);
oCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
foreach (Parameter oParam in oliGetProcParams)
{
    OracleParameter oOracleParam = new OracleParameter();
    oOracleParam.ParameterName = oParam.ParamName;
    oOracleParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
    oOracleParam.Direction = oParam.ParamDirection;
    oOracleParam.OracleType = oParam.ParamDataType;
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(oOracleParam);
}

OracleParameter oCVParam = new OracleParameter("cv_1", OracleType.Cursor);
oCVParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
oCommand.Parameters.Add(oCVParam);

OracleDataReader oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader();                

if (oReader != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < oReader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        CustomField oField = new CustomField();
        oField.Name = oReader.GetName(i);
        oField.DataType = oReader.GetFieldType(i).ToString();
        oliFields.Add(oField);
    }
}
#endregion

oCommand.Dispose();
oReader.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable()` to get the metadata `DataTable`, which contains more information about the types, including the precision and scale.

The schema table has a row for each column in the data reader, and columns like `ColumnName` and `NumericPrecision` / `NumericScale`. So you can walk one row after another and get all the metadata you need.

However, do note that you still need to read the value as `decimal` - the provider *will* give it to you as `decimal`. You should be able to map those manually to more proper types, though. Default number precisions are a bit annoying on Oracle, though, so it's quite likely you'll need to stick with `decimal` anyway (`number(20, 0)` is too big for `long` even though it's an integer).

Comment: That is great, one thing though, if I need to define the variables as int/double only, how should I set the field type based on the precision and scale (I mean based on what condition)?

Comment: @KarimAG The closest to `int` would be `number(9)`, or better, `binary_integer`. `double` is a completely different concept - it's a binary number, not decimal; the correct type on oracle is `binary_double`. I wouldn't bother with it if you're used to working with `number` - stick to `decimal`s, they behave the same as `number`.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the helpful answer, one last question, I am using T4 to generate the CS file, the problem is that `DataRow.Field` method is an extension method and you cannot use extension methods inside T4 template, do you have an alternative for this method that can provide the same function?

Comment: @KarimAG Really? I don't see why it would be disabled... Aren't you just missing the proper namespace (`System.Data`)?  Anyway, you can call the method manually (`System.Data.DataRowExtensions.Field``1`), or use the old way to get values (`row[columnNameOrIndex]`).

Comment: My fault, my code was missing the import tag of System.Data.DataSetExtensions, thanks a lot @Luaan

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it casting the values to typeof int in a try catch, if it's not a int it should be a double.

That the approach i would try.

Comment: This won't work because I am dealing with FieldType not with values of the row, so there is no value to cast and check if the casting worked.